# Rewrite php array, change level of key

Tags: php, loops, foreach, associative-array

I want to rewrite this associative array and switch the level of the value of the key [unique_name] to the first level. Any ideas?

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [value] => value1
        [name] => name1
        [unique_name] => unique1
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [value] => value2
        [name] => name2
        [unique_name] => unique2
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [value] => value3
        [name] => name3
        [unique_name] => unique3
    )
)
```

Desired output:

```
Array (
    [unique1] => Array (
        [value] => value1
        [name] => name1
    )
    [unique2] => Array (
        [value] => value2
        [name] => name2
    )
    [unique3] => Array (
        [value] => value3
        [name] => name3
    )
)
```

Cheers,
Adnan

Comment: easy, foreach() loop, give it a go and let us know if you need help, with code

Comment: If you want to 'do programming', it will bless you much more to 'do' and 'fail', then seek help. More education is gained in the 'doing' then you will ever receive 'asking'

Comment: As Dagon says, just a `foreach` loop. Rather then 'altering' the array, just create a new one in the format you want.

Comment: @Rottingham very true, I try not to ask too much on stack but the responses are so quick and good haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following loop:

```
// create an array to hold the new schema
$uniques = array();

// loop over all the records
foreach ($records as $record) {
    $uniques[$record['unique_name']] = $record;

    // remove the unique_name entry from the new array
    unset($uniques[$record['unique_name']]['unique_name']);
}
```

You could just as easily do a hardcoded key-set within the loop, but this will have less portability if you add new indexes later on:

```
foreach ($records as $record) {
    $uniques[$record['unique_name']] = array(
        'name' => $record['name'],
        'value' => $record['value']
    );
}
```

Comment: Great answer, upvoted it since it's not hardcoded and has nice comments. The array_diff_key flip is also creative though! Will accept answer in 3 min.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array();

foreach ($array as $entry) {
    $result[$array['unique_name']] = array_diff_key($entry, array_flip(array('unique_name')));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $item){
    $newarray[$item['unique_name']] = array('name' => $item['name'], 'value' => $item['value']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, a version using a lambda function with a closure:

```
$input = Array (
    Array ("value" => "value1", "name" => "name1", "unique_name" => "unique1"),
    Array ("value" => "value2", "name" => "name2", "unique_name" => "unique2"),
    Array ("value" => "value3", "name" => "name3", "unique_name" => "unique3"));

function set_unique_key ($array, $key)
{
    return array_reduce (
        $array,
        function ($res, $elem) use ($key) { 
            $res[$elem[$key]] = array_diff_key ($elem, array ("$key"=>''));
            return $res;
            }, 
        array());
}

print_r (set_unique_key ($input, 'unique_name'));
```